# How do I replace the button style in mailchimp CSS embed code?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, embed, mailchimp

I can't figure out how to change the button style or position in Mailchimp's embed CSS, below:

```
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; }
/* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style 
block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. 
*/
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://7grainarmy.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post? 
u=e6f00f0dccb61295ecf1b51c4&amp;id=ebaa28ce5c" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<div class="mc-field-group">
<label for="mce-EMAIL">email address <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove 
this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" 
name="b_e6f00f0dccb61295ecf1b51c4_ebaa28ce5c" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Sign up" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded- 
subscribe" class="button"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

--
Firstly, I would like to move the button to center, and I would like to replace the button with a clickable image as I have a stylized button I'd like to use. How can I do this? I'm using thee Slider Revolution plugin on Wordpress and this is the website I'm working on: http://laurenb9.sg-host.com/

Thank you!

Comment: What have tried so far to style the button ( which seems to the div with class button), for example have you tried setting its background-image?

Answer (score 0):

Below adds custom css to center the button and comments for where to adds your bg styles:

```html
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" 
   type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
   #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; }
   /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style 
   block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. 
   */
   #mc_embed_signup .button {
     /* center button */
     margin: auto;
     display: block;
     
     /* add your other bg override styles here */
   }
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
   <form action="https://7grainarmy.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post? 
      u=e6f00f0dccb61295ecf1b51c4&amp;id=ebaa28ce5c" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
      name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
      <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
         <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-EMAIL">email address <span class="asterisk">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
         </div>
         <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
         </div>
         <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove 
            this or risk form bot signups-->
         <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" 
            name="b_e6f00f0dccb61295ecf1b51c4_ebaa28ce5c" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
         <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Sign up" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded- 
            subscribe" class="button"></div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This didn't work for centering the button though, do you know what might have gone wrong? Or is there another way to try?

Comment: There must be other styles on the page clashing.  The button is centered here for me when I "Run code snippet".